# How to convert a specific date format into a proper data type and query related records between dates?

Tags: datetime, neo4j, cypher

I am learning neo4j and have a problem where a given data set I have uploaded has a weird date format which I can't query using neo4j's bult in date functions because it was uploaded as a string. The format is the following:

`╒══════════════════════════╕
 │"t.date"                  │
 ╞══════════════════════════╡
 │"Mon 18 Feb 2019 12:18:57"│
 ├──────────────────────────┤
 │"Mon 18 Feb 2019 12:18:57"│
 └──────────────────────────┘`

I have already created a node that contains `date` as a property and stores the dates in the above format.

How can I change this so I can query the associated node to return results `BETWEEN` certain dates, so for example:

`MATCH (t:Text)
 WHERE t.date = 'Mon 18 Feb 2019 12:18:57'
 RETURN t.description;`

I would need to be able to query for `Texts` in between certain dates for example texts written in between `Mon 18 Feb 2019 12:18:57` and `Mon 19 Feb 2019 12:18:57`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are two ways:**

1. Change the existing date property to Neo4j `'DateTime'`. Which can be easily queried. (*RECOMMENDED*)
2. Keep the date property as it is and use apoc to compare the date each time you want to query. *(NOT RECOMMENDED)*

You can use [**`apoc.date.parse`**](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#datetime-conversions) function from **APOC Plugin** to parse the ***date string*** into ***epoch time*** by specifying the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

**You can use the following query to change your existing dates into Neo4j `'DateTime'`: (For Solution 1)**

```
MATCH (n:Text)
WHERE n.date IS NOT NULL
SET n.date=datetime({epochmillis:apoc.date.parse(n.date, 'ms',"EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")})
```

**Refer** [Neo4j DateTime](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/datetime/)

**Note:** Install [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) before running above query.

Comment: Thanks Raj, when I use the following query to set `MATCH (node:Text)
SET node.date = datetime(node.date);` it does not work as it looks at days described in three letters `Mon` and says string can't be parsed into datetime which makes complete sense. Would you be able to share a query for your first suggested solution?

Comment: The query I shared is for my first solution. Use it as it is, it parse your date.

Comment: Don't skip the apoc parse from my query, that's what which does the conversion.

Comment: After conversion use Neo4j datetime to compare with nodes date time. Please check another answer which explains this.

Answer (score 1):

Once you convert the date string into datetime format, you can do below query to get text description when date is between Feb 18 and 19 12:18:57.  Notice the letter 'T' at the middle. It means time.

```
MATCH (t:Text)
 WHERE t.date > datetime('2019-02-18T12:18:57') 
   AND t.date < datetime('2019-02-19T12:18:57')
 RETURN t.description;
```

Reference:
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/datetime/#functions-datetime-create-string